# How JAVAFX and Bootstrap-CSS will integrate

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

How do I integrate JavaFX and Bootstrap CSS?

Is there a dependency we have to add to Maven to achieve this?

Comment: read [ask], and show your research and efforts

Comment: What do you actually mean by integrating these? As far as I am aware, Bootstrap CSS is a CSS-based layout library for HTML pages. If you are just wanting to use it in HTML pages that are displayed in a JavaFX `WebView`, there should be nothing to do other than include the library in the HTML pages in the usual way. If you are expecting to use Bootstrap CSS to lay out your JavaFX components, that simply won't work.